# Tikz: get the point at the arc end

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I draw an arc I get, through the `coordinate` command, the point at the end of the arc (`mypoint` in the code below) for further drawing, but it does not correspond to the expected point.

See the drawing: the **green** circle should lay at the end of the **red** arc (where I have placed *manually* a **blue** circle), as expected in the code, but it lays some millimetres away.

How could I get the "right" point at the end of the arc for further drawing?

[image: arc with circle]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\newcommand{\xradius}{0.22}
\newcommand{\yradius}{0.17}
%Ellipses centre
\newcommand{\xcent}{2}
\newcommand{\ycent}{2}

\newcommand{\myrotation}{20} %Ellipse rotation angle
\newcommand{\myangle}{30} %Angle before axis

\coordinate (center) at (\xcent, \ycent);

\draw (center) circle [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius, rotate=\myrotation]; %Drawing black ellipse

\path (center) ++({-90+\myrotation}:\yradius) coordinate (startpoint); %Starting point of red arc

\draw [color=red] (startpoint) arc [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius, start angle={-90}, delta angle={90-\myangle/2}, 
rotate=\myrotation] coordinate (mypoint);  %Drawing red arc and getting the end point
\path [fill=green, radius=0.02] (mypoint) circle; %Drawing green circle

\draw [help lines] (center) -- +(\myrotation:{4*\xradius}); %Gray reference axis

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Oh, yes, thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following suggestions will work with both the current pgf version (3.0.1a) and the old version 2.10.

Use `rotate=\myrotation` as option for the whole path:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \newcommand{\xradius}{0.22}
  \newcommand{\yradius}{0.17}
  %Ellipses centre
  \newcommand{\xcent}{2}
  \newcommand{\ycent}{2}

  \newcommand{\myrotation}{20} %Ellipse rotation angle
  \newcommand{\myangle}{30} %Angle before axis

  \coordinate (center) at (\xcent, \ycent);
  \draw[rotate=\myrotation] (center) circle [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius];
  \path[rotate=\myrotation] (center) ++(-90:\yradius) coordinate (startpoint); 
  \draw [color=red,rotate=\myrotation] (startpoint) 
    arc [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius, start angle={-90}, delta angle={90-\myangle/2}] 
    coordinate (mypoint);
  \path [fill=green, radius=0.02] (mypoint) circle;
  \draw [help lines] (center) -- +(\myrotation:{4*\xradius});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or using a scope for the rotation:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
  \newcommand{\xradius}{0.22}
  \newcommand{\yradius}{0.17}
  %Ellipses centre
  \newcommand{\xcent}{2}
  \newcommand{\ycent}{2}

  \newcommand{\myrotation}{20} %Ellipse rotation angle
  \newcommand{\myangle}{30} %Angle before axis

  \coordinate (center) at (\xcent, \ycent);

  \begin{scope}[rotate=\myrotation]
    \draw (center) circle [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius];
    \path (center) ++(-90:\yradius) coordinate (startpoint); 
    \draw [color=red] (startpoint) 
      arc [x radius=\xradius, y radius=\yradius, start angle={-90}, delta angle={90-\myangle/2}] 
      coordinate (mypoint);
    \draw [help lines] (center) -- +({4*\xradius},0);
  \end{scope}

  \path [fill=green, radius=0.02] (mypoint) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! the trick of using `rotate=\myrotation` for the whole path did it. Thanks again @esdd! By the way, nice suggestion of creating a scope for the rotation, that's what I'll use! :)

Answer (score 2):

Compiling your MWE results in this:
[image]

Seems to me that the green spot is spot on!

Comment: Did you get that with my code? How can it be that the same code by me produces my picture??

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus, I got the same, my guess is that you need to update your LaTeX installation